# C# xml with multiple sections to dictionary conversion

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a configuration file  which looks like

```
 <configuration>

  <setings1>

    <a>False</a>
    <c>True</c>

  </setings1>

  <Settings2>
    <b>10</b>
  </Settings2>

</configuration>
```

How  to convert to dictionary(string,list(string,string)) i.e settings as key and elements as sub values

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(dllconfigpath);

            var allelements = doc.Descendants(); --- i tried to do this but i get all elements in the xml

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to enumerate child elements of `Root` node as settings items and then enumerate every `setting` element to get a child values

```cs
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<(string key, string value)>>();
foreach (var element in document.Root.Elements())
{
    var list = new List<(string key, string value)>();
    foreach (var child in element.Elements())
    {
        list.Add((child.Name.ToString(), child.Value));
    }
    dict.Add(element.Name.ToString(), list);
}
```

[`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) in C# doesn't support two generic type parameters, so you can't declare it like `List<string,string>`.

You can use a list of tuples, like in sample above or create your own object to represent the key and value or use build-in `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` class

Answer (score 1):

Using XMl Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication157
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> dict = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.ToUpper().StartsWith("SETTINGS"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName.ToUpper(), y => y.Elements().Select(a => new List<string> { a.Name.LocalName, (string)a }).ToList())
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use any hardcoded strings like : "SETTINGS"

Comment: Then you want all elements under configuration?  Then use doc.Descendents("configuration").Elemements().GroupBy(..........